# My dedicated server accept only 777 for uploads

Tags: apache

I don't know if somebody can help me, but i have a dedicated server on linux and the problem is only the 777 rule accepts uploads or write.
 if the path of my site is /var/www/ffolder/data/www/mysite.com how i can enable the rule 755 for uploads and write?
best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that the owner of `/var/www/ffolder/data/www/mysite.com` are the same you use to try the upload.

If the upload is made by some script ran by Apache or nginx, the user owning the directory must be the same user used to start the webserver.